# How do I control the completion of this ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been learning ajax for a week and I am trying to figure out how I hope to finish the ajax function.

In my function of jquery I get the id of several buttons that I have in my index, that id sent it by ajax to an external file called "task-category.php '" that the only thing it does is an sql query to my database and it returns its answer in the form of JSON, when I receive the JSON I go through it and I'm printing at the same time with ajax in my index.

My problem arises when I want to know in what moment I have finished traveling all the json ajax to print on the index screen that "the search has been carried out successfully" or "no data was found".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    $('ul#categoria li').click(function() {

      let categoria = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'task-categoria.php',
        data: {categoria},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
          if(!response.error) {
            let tasks = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            tasks.forEach(task => {
              template += `<a href='index.php?idrec=${task.idrec}'>
                     <div class="img-container grid-item">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="${task.imag}">
            <div class="overlay">
               <span>${task.tit}</span>
            </div>
         </div>
         </a>` 
            });
      
            $('#grid-container').html(template);
          }
        } 
      
      })
    });
 
});
```

Comment: You'd need to give us a full working example if possible, either by updating your snippet or creating a fiddle

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: have a look at callback functions. In simple words, in your success section of the ajax call you will add another part (after the one you have) that will be executed after the first finish. with callbacks you can have two different for success and error. Or you can use complete to have a single callback triggered no matter how the ajax ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the flow of ajax is like this

[image: ajax flow]

you can use **success** to do main output and then **complete** to say its completed

Answer (score 0):

Make your api response good so you can handle it easily if you can else add your condition according to api response.Your api response should be as below

```
{'status': true, 'error': false, 'data': ['your data'], 'message':"Data Fetch successfully"}
```

I have done some changes as below:-
     $(document).ready(function() {

```
$('ul#categoria li').click(function() {

  let categoria = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'task-categoria.php',
    data: {categoria},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
    // Best thing to do is that always use status of response true/false
      if(!response.error) {
      if(response.status == true) {
        let tasks = JSON.parse(response);
        let template = '';
        tasks.forEach(task => {
          template += `<a href='index.php?idrec=${task.idrec}'>
                 <div class="img-container grid-item">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="${task.imag}">
        <div class="overlay">
           <span>${task.tit}</span>
        </div>
     </div>
     </a>` 
        });

        $('#grid-container').html(template);
      }
      alert('data fetch successfully');
      } else {
      alert('No data found');
      }
    },error: function (error) {
        console.log('Some error occured please try later!');
    }

  })
});

});
```