# JQuery Ajax Data Upload Complete Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

In my usecase, the user is supposed to upload a big file (about 100MB) and then that file is processed in the backend. The backend process is a PHP script with `ignore_user_abort(true)` so the script keeps processing the file even if the user closes the browser.

I need to inform the user once the upload part is complete that they can now close the window and check the result later.

I am using JQuery and `$.ajax` doesn't seem to have an event which triggers when upload part of the Ajax call is completed. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You can try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54441765/2996989) how ajax events works in sequence , and then call it on complete,  or ajaxComplete . [here](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) is the difference

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax has callbacks, you could use `.done()` or `.fail()`.

```
$.ajax({
   ...
}).done(function(status){
   alert(status + "completed.");
}).fail(function(){
   alert(status + "failed.");
});
```

Comment: Done or Fail only triggers when the complete process (i.e. Sending and receiving process data) is done. What I need is something which triggers when only Data send is complete.